# Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNCSafeAreaProvider" was not found in the UIManager

Tags: react-native, expo

Implementing React Navigate in the project installing the package `npm install @react-navigation/native @react-navigation/stack` shows the following error.

[image: THIS IS MY ERROR]

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: You are forgot run pod install check document againt https://github.com/react-navigation/react-native-safe-area-view

Comment: Props for showing the error message, but it should ideally be in text rather than an image.  Also, we'll need to see some example code that produces the error (unless what Anh mentioned is the only possible cause of this).

Answer (score 52, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Try upgrading your expo CLI with `npm install -g expo-cli` and running `expo update` to fix the dependencies.

**My case**

I experienced this issue today in an expo app while trying to setup React Navigation.

I noticed this message in the console when launching expo

```
Some of your project's dependencies are not compatible with currently installed expo package version:
 - react-native-reanimated - expected version range: ~1.7.0 - actual version installed: ^1.9.0
 - react-native-screens - expected version range: ~2.2.0 - actual version installed: ^2.8.0
 - react-native-safe-area-context - expected version range: 0.7.3 - actual version installed: ^2.0.0
 - @react-native-community/masked-view - expected version range: 0.1.6 - actual version installed: ^0.1.10
Your project may not work correctly until you install the correct versions of the packages.
To install the correct versions of these packages, please run: expo install [package-name ...]
```

Updating expo and running expo update to set the dependencies to something compatible with my SDK seemed to solve the issue for me

```
npm install -g expo-cli
expo update
```

I noticed that some dependencies were reverted to older versions that now seem to work. E.g. (in package.json):

```
-"react-native-safe-area-context": "^2.0.0",
+"react-native-safe-area-context": "0.7.3",
```

Even when the warning message explicitly instructed me to run the `expo install` for each problematic dependency, doing so would lead to the same version that was throwing the error.

Comment: I had the same issue while using `@react-navigation` the way I resolved is by installing `"react-native-safe-area-context": "3.2.0"` in package.json

Comment: Since `expo` CLI is deprecated, `npx expo install --fix` is here to fix dependencies.

Answer (score 49):

Stop running your app. Do **npx pod-install ios**. Then rebuild your app. This worked for me.

Comment: Just to clarify: you need to rebuild the app in xcode, not just your js bundle in metro

Answer (score 3):

`expo update` did not work for me unfortunately :(

When running `yarn start` in my console, I got:

```
Some of your project's dependencies are not compatible with currently installed expo package version:
 - react-native-reanimated - expected version range: ~1.7.0 - actual version installed: ^1.9.0
 - react-native-screens - expected version range: ~2.2.0 - actual version installed: ^2.8.0
 - react-native-safe-area-context - expected version range: 0.7.3 - actual version installed: ^3.0.2
 - @react-native-community/masked-view - expected version range: 0.1.6 - actual version installed: ^0.1.10
Your project may not work correctly until you install the correct versions of the packages.
To install the correct versions of these packages, please run: expo install [package-name ...]
```

I ran `expo install <package>@<version>` for each of the shown packages, and it is working now!

Comment: Fyi, you can run `expo doctor --fix-dependencies` to fix those