# Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNCSafeAreaProvider" was not found in the UIManager error

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

**Hello everybody, can someone help me with this issue? i had try all the possible solutions with the same problem but i don't have the solution yet.**

[image]

**This is my package.json**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This answer helped me.
[Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNCSafeAreaProvider" was not found in the UIManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61967017/invariant-violation-requirenativecomponent-rncsafeareaprovider-was-not-found#comment-109599542)

Try to install react-native-safe-area-view.
`$ yarn add react-native-safe-area-view`
And re-install pods.
`$ npx pod-install ios`
Then, start react-native.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to run this in your app folder:

```
$ cd ios && pod install
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use previous or different version of `react-native-safe-area-context`.
it worked for me by downgrade to one minor version.