# An issue with React-Native rendering a component

Tags: javascript, react-native

ERROR

> Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

### Check the render method of `User`.

```
import User from './Components/User';
```

---

```
return(
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <View>
      <User details={details} />
    </View>
  </View>
)
```

---

User component

```
import React from 'react';
import {Image, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native'
import {
  Card,
  CardItem,
  H1,
} from 'native-base'
import moment from 'moment'

const User = ({details}) => {
    return(
        <Card style={styles.card}>
          <CardItem cardBody style={styles.cardItem}>
            <Image
            source={{
              uri: details.picture?.large,
              width: 150,
              height: 250
            }}
            style={styles.image}
            />
          </CardItem>

          <CardItem style={styles.cardItem}>
            <H1 style={styles.text}>
              {details.name?.title} {details.name?.first} {details.name?.last}
            </H1>
          </CardItem>

          <CardItem bordered style={styles.cardItem}>
            <Text style={styles.text}>
              {details.cell}
            </Text>
          </CardItem>

          <CardItem footer style={styles.cardItem}>
            <Text style={{color: '#fff'}}>
              Registered at 
              {moment(details.registered?.text).format('DD-MM-YY')}
            </Text>
          </CardItem>

        </Card>
    )
}

export default User;
```

Comment: could you please show `User` code?

Comment: Edited in the above!

Comment: What version of `native-base` are you using?

Comment: Native-base: 3.1.0

Comment: Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have installed `native-base` v3 and importing `native-base` v2 components ( `Card`,  `CardItem`, `H1` ) etc. You will have to import the correct components and rewrite your `User` component.

The `Card`, `CardItem` components are not there in `v3` and can be easily built using components like `Box`. The `H1` component is also replaced with a component `Heading`.

https://docs.nativebase.io/migration/card

Comment: Now I am getting log as below:
LOG  [Error: useTheme: `theme` is undefined. Seems you forgot to wrap your app in `<NativeBaseProvider />`]

Comment: You will have to wrap your whole app with `NativeBaseProvider`. https://docs.nativebase.io/setup-provider

Comment: Do I need to wrap it in User component also?

Comment: No.  Wrap it on your root level as suggested in the Doc

Comment: LOG  [Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNCSafeAreaProvider" was not found in the UIManager.]
 ERROR  Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNCSafeAreaProvider" was not found in the UIManager.

I did as doc said, now I am facing this

Comment: I don't think it has nothing to do with the OP. try this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61967017/invariant-violation-requirenativecomponent-rncsafeareaprovider-was-not-found

Comment: I checked that earlier, but didn't go all way good..(

Answer (score 0):

try exporting like this

```
export default function User () {
// ... code goes here
}
```

you can also use anonymous function in a default export