# React Native KeyboardAvoidingView is not working as expected

Tags: react-native

The screen is Wrapped inside KeyboardAvoidingView and ScrollView components. Some of the last inputs are partially hidden by the keyboard. If I set the `behaviour` prop to anything, but undefined a white element comes up after keyboard. All I would like to do is to make the screen scroll down like 20 more pixels... I feel like I have tried everything so far, even setting the `keyboardVerticalOffset` prop, but nothing seems to work. If that offset was transparent it would be perfect...

In the following code a `View component` is passed to `children` prop

```js
import { FunctionComponent, ReactNode } from 'react';
import { KeyboardAvoidingView, ScrollView } from 'react-native';

interface WrapperProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}

const KeyboardAvoidingWrapper: FunctionComponent<WrapperProps> = ({children}) => {
  return (
    <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior='height' keyboardVerticalOffset={100}>
      <ScrollView>
        {children}
      </ScrollView>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
  );
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead, You can use react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my issue with: [react-native-avoid-softinput](https://mateusz1913.github.io/react-native-avoid-softinput/)

**INSTALLATION:**

`yarn add react-native-avoid-softinput`

On iOS additionally run: `npx pod-install`

**USAGE:**

```js
import React from "react";
import { AvoidSoftInputView } from "react-native-avoid-softinput";

const MyComponent = () => {
  return (
    <AvoidSoftInputView>
      {/** Content that should be pushed above the keyboard */}
    </AvoidSoftInputView>
  );
};
```

**TROUBLESHOOTING**:

> requireNativeComponent: "AvoidSoftInputView" was not found in the UIManager.

Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65513391/14056591

Try again `cd ios && pod install`

If it doesn't help, try restarting the simulator, delete and rebuild the app. Restarting Xcode and metro bundler is also a good idea.

If this does not solve your issue, I came across another promising library, but I did not get to use it: [react-native-keyboard-controller](https://kirillzyusko.github.io/react-native-keyboard-controller/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the second library won't work for me and the first one gives the error: `requireNativeComponent: "AvoidSoftInputView" was not found in the UIManager.`

Comment: @NándorKrizbai Check updated answer I personally had lots of issues with react-native-aware-scroll-view and that’s how I got to the mentioned library

Comment: Indeed, the aware-scroll-view is not working perfectly on IOS. I think I'm unable to use `react-native-avoid-softinput`, because it's an Expo project. I would need to eject to ExpoKit, which I can't do right now...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61967017/invariant-violation-requirenativecomponent-rncsafeareaprovider-was-not-found - You can also try solutions from Expo here. Sorry, I don't have much experience with Expo.

Comment: I tried all the solutions, I think it's just not supported in Expo yet...